# Downscaling 4K YUV420 to 1080p YUV444 with ffmpeg introduces red tint

Tags: ffmpeg, 4k, scale, vlc

I am downscaling 4K YUV420 video from the Panasonic LX100 to Full HD YUV444 using the ffmpeg console in Windows, and a script provided by [user karl on the Personal View forum](http://www.personal-view.com/talks/discussion/10637/4k-downscaling-progress-topic/p3), modified for outputting H265 video at constant rate factor 18:

```
ffmpeg -i "input_path.MP4" -filter_complex "extractplanes=y+u+v[y][u][v]; [u] scale=w=3840:h=2160:flags=print_info+neighbor+bitexact [us]; [v] scale=w=3840:h=2160:flags=print_info+neighbor+bitexact [vs]; [y][us][vs]mergeplanes=0x001020:yuv444p,format=pix_fmts=yuv444p10le,scale=w=1920:h=1080:flags=print_info+bicubic+full_chroma_inp+full_chroma_int" -sws_dither none  -c:v libx265 -preset medium -crf 18 -c:a copy  -c:s copy -c:d copy  -map 0 "output_path.mp4"
```

The result, VLC tells me, is a 1080p yuv444 video, and I can see excellent color resolution, so far so good. However, the image has a slight red tint compared to the original.

What could cause that?

The full console output is:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.MP4" -filter_complex "extractplanes=y+u+v[y][u][v]; [u] scale=w=3840:h=2160:flags=print_info+neighbor+bitexact [us]; [v] scale=w=3840:h=2160:flags=print_info+neighbor+bitexact [vs]; [y
][us][vs]mergeplanes=0x001020:yuv444p,format=pix_fmts=yuv444p10le,scale=w=1920:h
=1080:flags=print_info+bicubic+full_chroma_inp+full_chroma_int" -sws_dither none
  -c:v libx265 -preset medium -crf 18 -c:a copy  -c:s copy -c:d copy  -map 0 "output.mp4"
ffmpeg version N-82080-g6969bed Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dx
va2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-lib
ebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --ena
ble-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfree
type --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enab
le-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-lib
openh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschr
oedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheor
a --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvo
rbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --ena
ble-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --e
nable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 32.100 / 55. 32.100
  libavcodec     57. 63.103 / 57. 63.103
  libavformat    57. 53.100 / 57. 53.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.103 / 57.  0.103
  libavfilter     6. 64.100 /  6. 64.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp42avc1
    creation_time   : 2015-06-27T21:42:33.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:16.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 95327 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709)
, 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 95071 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 360k tbn, 47.9
5 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-06-27T21:42:33.000000Z
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, flt
p, 124 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-06-27T21:42:33.000000Z
File 'output.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[swscaler @ 00000000041193c0] nearest neighbor / point scaler, from gray to gray
 using MMXEXT
[swscaler @ 0000000000556720] nearest neighbor / point scaler, from gray to gray
 using MMXEXT
[swscaler @ 000000000418cd60] bicubic scaler, from yuv444p10le to yuv444p using
MMXEXT
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 0.0
x265 [info]: build info [Windows][GCC 5.4.0][64 bit] 8bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
x265 [info]: Main 4:4:4 profile, Level-4 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 4 threads
x265 [info]: Slices                              : 1
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 2 / wpp(17 rows)
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 8
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intra
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : hex / 57 / 2 / 2
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut       : 23 / 250 / 40
x265 [info]: Cb/Cr QP Offset                     : 6 / 6
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 20 / 4 / 2
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb       : 1 / 1 / 0
x265 [info]: References / ref-limit  cu / depth  : 3 / on / on
x265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 1 / 1.0 / 32 / 1
x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress            : CRF-18.0 / 0.60
x265 [info]: tools: rd=3 psy-rd=2.00 rskip signhide tmvp strong-intra-smoothing
x265 [info]: tools: lslices=6 deblock sao
Output #0, mp4, to 'G:\darrask\Pics\2015.06 Goettingen\P1340763_karl3.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp42avc1
    encoder         : Lavf57.53.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (libx265) ([35][0][0][0] / 0x0023), yuv444p, 1920x1
080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 23.98 fps, 24k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.63.103 libx265
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, 124 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-06-27T21:42:33.000000Z
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> extractplanes
  scale -> Stream #0:0 (libx265)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 00000000041b9da0] bicubic scaler, from yuv444p10le to yuv444p using MMXEXT
frame=    7 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=
frame=   17 fps= 16 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.49 bitrate=   0.7kbits/s
frame=   25 fps= 16 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.98 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s
frame=   29 fps= 14 q=-0.0 size=      61kB time=00:00:00.98 bitrate= 508.0kbits/
frame=   30 fps= 11 q=-0.0 size=      95kB time=00:00:00.98 bitrate= 795.6kbits/
frame=   31 fps=9.7 q=-0.0 size=     112kB time=00:00:01.00 bitrate= 918.1kbits/
...console output truncated by user...
frame=  377 fps=3.9 q=-0.0 size=    7017kB time=00:00:15.50 bitrate=3706.4kbits/
frame=  379 fps=3.9 q=-0.0 size=    7048kB time=00:00:15.53 bitrate=3717.4kbits/
frame=  383 fps=3.9 q=-0.0 size=    7131kB time=00:00:16.00 bitrate=3650.8kbits/
frame=  384 fps=3.7 q=-0.0 Lsize=    7561kB time=00:00:16.00 bitrate=3871.5kbits
/s speed=0.156x
video:7304kB audio:244kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:1kB muxin
g overhead: 0.169810%
x265 [info]: frame I:      2, Avg QP:18.71  kb/s: 16117.16
x265 [info]: frame P:     86, Avg QP:19.53  kb/s: 8568.68
x265 [info]: frame B:    296, Avg QP:23.40  kb/s: 2247.32
x265 [info]: Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
x265 [info]: consecutive B-frames: 2.3% 0.0% 9.1% 36.4% 52.3%

encoded 384 frames in 102.81s (3.73 fps), 3735.28 kb/s, Avg QP:22.51

output_path
>
```

Note it also has a red tint when I export to Prores with the original script by karl, and also when pix_fmts=yuv444p10le is not used (thus I presume 8 bits per pixel are used).

Comment: Show the full console output.

Comment: Done and edited.

Answer (score 3):

I dug further and after reading the entire topic at [Personal View](http://www.personal-view.com/talks/discussion/10637/4k-downscaling-progress-topic/p4), I found that user [willyfan](http://www.personal-view.com/talks/profile/235/willyfan) suggested to add `in_range=full` to both first `scale` arguments to correct a color shift that he also observed. And it works. So here is the full ffmpeg code, adapted from karl's script, for windows:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.MP4" -filter_complex "extractplanes=y+u+v[y][u][v]; [u] scale=w=3840:h=2160:in_range=full:flags=print_info+neighbor+bitexact [us]; [v] scale=w=3840:h=2160:in_range=full:flags=print_info+neighbor+bitexact [vs]; [y][us][vs]mergeplanes=0x001020:yuv444p,format=pix_fmts=yuv444p10le,scale=w=1920:h=1080:flags=print_info+bicubic+full_chroma_inp+full_chroma_int" -sws_dither none  -c:v libx265 -preset medium -crf 18 -c:a copy  -c:s copy -c:d copy  -map 0 "output.mp4"
```

So it seems that this is a good working script for converting 4K YUV420 footage to 1080p YUV444 footage with amazing results! My files are 5-10% the original size and have incredibly little quality loss.

PS: note that user karl says:

> But if you use "in_rage=full:out_range=full", that should be fine with
>   material recorded in the 0-255 value range. [...] You could try to use
>   "in_range=full:out_range=mpeg" and see if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

huh?
I would just use ffmpeg v4.x now and just use a command like
ffmpeg -i "infile" -c:v libx265 -pix_fmt yuv444p -crf 18 "outfile"

Comment: this is not what is needed. We need to go from 4K YUK420 to 1080p YUV444 and this does not even downscale.